# Deciding threshold for glm logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, glm, predict, logistic-regression

I have some data with predictors and a binary target. Eg:

```
df <- data.frame(a=sort(sample(1:100,30)), b= sort(sample(1:100,30)), 
                 target=c(rep(0,11),rep(1,4),rep(0,4),rep(1,11)))
```

I trained a logistic regresion model using `glm()`

```
model1 <- glm(formula= target ~ a + b, data=df, family=binomial)
```

Now I'm trying to predict the output (for the example, the same data should suffice)

```
predict(model1, newdata=df, type="response")
```

This generates a vector of probability numbers. But I want to predict the actual class. I could use round() on the probablity numbers, but this assumes that anything below 0.5 is class '0', and anything above  is class '1'. Is this a correct assumption? Even when the population of each class may not be equal (or close to equal)? Or is there a way to estimate this threshold?

Comment: there are different criteria, one for example is the point where the sum of sensitivity and specificity is maximal, see for example this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131897/how-can-i-get-the-optimal-cutoff-point-of-the-roc-in-logistic-regression-as-a-nu/23133261#23133261

Comment: @adibender Thanks! But it would be certainly incorrect to use the threshold as the population fraction, right? That is, if in the population, 30% cases are '0's, and 70% '1's, a naive estimate would be to use 0.3 as the threshold. But this would not be a logical way to approach this?

Comment: You can find a great tutorial on the subject here: https://hopstat.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/a-small-introduction-to-the-rocr-package/

Answer (score 8):

The best threshold (or cutoff) point to be used in glm models is the point which maximises the specificity and the sensitivity. This threshold point might not give the highest prediction in your model, but it wouldn't be biased towards positives or negatives. The `ROCR` package contain functions that can help you do this. check the `performance()` function in this package. It is going to get you what you're looking for. Here's a picture of what you are expecting to get:

[image]

After finding the cutoff point, I normally write a function myself to find the number of datapoints that has their prediction value above the cutoff, and match it with the group they belong to.

Comment: could you provide a more specific code that would generate the above graph? Also, how can cutoff values be between 0 and 14 for probabilities that take values between 0 and 1?

Comment: I added baseR/ggplot approaches below!

Answer (score 4):

The gold standard for determining good model parameters, including "what threshold should I set" for logistic regression, is **cross-validation**.

The general idea is to hold out one or more parts of your training set and choose the threshold that maximizes the number of correct classifications on this held-out set, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) can give you many more details.

Comment: Since we'd be tuning the threshold parameter on the cross validation data, ostensibly, that would require a third held out set for evaluation to report an unbiased expected error?

Comment: @user2175594, Yes that is correct. Traditionally you would have at least three separate partitions of your data: training, validation, and test (evaluation). However, if you are doing something like k-fold cross-validation, then training and validation are essentially the same set re-partitioned in multiple ways.

Answer (score 4):

Tooled around trying to replicate first graph. Given a `predictions <- prediction(pred,labels)` object, then:

baseR approach

```
plot(unlist(performance(predictions, "sens")@x.values), unlist(performance(predictions, "sens")@y.values), 
     type="l", lwd=2, ylab="Specificity", xlab="Cutoff")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(unlist(performance(predictions, "spec")@x.values), unlist(performance(predictions, "spec")@y.values), 
     type="l", lwd=2, col='red', ylab="", xlab="")
axis(4, at=seq(0,1,0.2),labels=z)
mtext("Specificity",side=4, padj=-2, col='red')
```

[image]

ggplot2 approach

```
sens <- data.frame(x=unlist(performance(predictions, "sens")@x.values), 
                   y=unlist(performance(predictions, "sens")@y.values))
spec <- data.frame(x=unlist(performance(predictions, "spec")@x.values), 
                   y=unlist(performance(predictions, "spec")@y.values))

sens %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(data=spec, aes(x,y,col="red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Specificity")) +
  labs(x='Cutoff', y="Sensitivity") +
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(colour = "red"), legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the threshold in the data with the closest sensitivity and specificity values (ie. the cross over in the graphs above) programmatically you can you this code which gets pretty close:

```
predictions = prediction(PREDS, LABELS)

sens = cbind(unlist(performance(predictions, "sens")@x.values), unlist(performance(predictions, "sens")@y.values))
spec = cbind(unlist(performance(predictions, "spec")@x.values), unlist(performance(predictions, "spec")@y.values))
sens[which.min(apply(sens, 1, function(x) min(colSums(abs(t(spec) - x))))), 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 12 methods implemented in the function `PresenceAbsence::optimal.thresholds` of `PresenceAbsence` package.

This is also covered in Freeman, E. A., & Moisen, G. G. (2008). A comparison of the performance of threshold criteria for binary classification in terms of predicted prevalence and kappa. Ecological Modelling, 217(1-2), 48-58.

Answer (score -3):

You can try the below:

```
perfspec <- performance(prediction.obj = pred, measure="spec", x.measure="cutoff")

plot(perfspec)

par(new=TRUE)

perfsens <- performance(prediction.obj = pred, measure="sens", x.measure="cutoff")

plot(perfsens)
```