# Roc curve and cut off point. Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, roc

I ran a logistic regression model and made predictions of the logit values. I used this to get the points on the ROC curve:

```
 from sklearn import metrics
 fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(Y_test,p)
```

I know `metrics.roc_auc_score` gives the area under the ROC curve. Can anyone tell me what command will find the optimal cut-off point (threshold value)?

Comment: The answer to your question is simply, np.argmax(tpr - fpr)

Comment: And if you want the threshold value, its just thresholds[np.argmax(tpr - fpr)]. Everything else is verbosity.

Comment: Can anyone speak to the difference between `thresholds[np.argmax(tpr - fpr)]` and the most upvoted answer function `threshold = Find_Optimal_Cutoff(data['true'], data['pred'])`? The thresholds are close, but different when I do an actual calculation.

Comment: I would argue that to find the optimal point, you're looking for the balance point of sensitivity and specificity or, the tpr and 1-fpr. If you have a particular reason not to have the minimum difference between sensitivity and specificity, I can understand. To me though, the optimal point for the threshold value would be `thresholds[np.argmin(abs(tpr-(1-fpr)))]`

Comment: If you consider the optimal threshold to be the point on the curve closest to the top left corner of the ROC-AUC graph, you may use `thresholds[np.argmin((1 - tpr) ** 2 + fpr ** 2)]`. But @cgnorthcutt's solution maximizes the Youden's J statistic, which seems to be the more accepted method. What is truly "optimal" for your situation depends on the relative costs of false positives and false negatives.

Comment: I do not really understand why no one mentions here that the assumption everyone makes is that the cost of a False Positive is equal to a True Positive. This is not always the case. Only with this assumption this question can be answered with a single optimum in the way that is described here. Full explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can do this [using the `epi` package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131897/how-can-i-get-the-optimal-cutoff-point-of-the-roc-in-logistic-regression-as-a-nu), however I could not find similar package or example in Python.

The optimal cut off point would be where “true positive rate” is **high** and the “false positive rate” is **low**. Based on this logic, I have pulled an example below to find optimal threshold.

## Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

# read the data in
df = pd.read_csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

# rename the 'rank' column because there is also a DataFrame method called 'rank'
df.columns = ["admit", "gre", "gpa", "prestige"]
# dummify rank
dummy_ranks = pd.get_dummies(df['prestige'], prefix='prestige')
# create a clean data frame for the regression
cols_to_keep = ['admit', 'gre', 'gpa']
data = df[cols_to_keep].join(dummy_ranks.iloc[:, 'prestige_2':])

# manually add the intercept
data['intercept'] = 1.0

train_cols = data.columns[1:]
# fit the model
result = sm.Logit(data['admit'], data[train_cols]).fit()
print result.summary()

# Add prediction to dataframe
data['pred'] = result.predict(data[train_cols])

fpr, tpr, thresholds =roc_curve(data['admit'], data['pred'])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print("Area under the ROC curve : %f" % roc_auc)

####################################
# The optimal cut off would be where tpr is high and fpr is low
# tpr - (1-fpr) is zero or near to zero is the optimal cut off point
####################################
i = np.arange(len(tpr)) # index for df
roc = pd.DataFrame({'fpr' : pd.Series(fpr, index=i),'tpr' : pd.Series(tpr, index = i), '1-fpr' : pd.Series(1-fpr, index = i), 'tf' : pd.Series(tpr - (1-fpr), index = i), 'thresholds' : pd.Series(thresholds, index = i)})
roc.iloc[(roc.tf-0).abs().argsort()[:1]]

# Plot tpr vs 1-fpr
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
pl.plot(roc['tpr'])
pl.plot(roc['1-fpr'], color = 'red')
pl.xlabel('1-False Positive Rate')
pl.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
pl.title('Receiver operating characteristic')
ax.set_xticklabels([])
```

The optimal cut off point is 0.317628, so anything above this can be labeled as 1 else 0. You can see from the output/chart that where TPR is crossing 1-FPR the TPR is 63%, FPR is 36% and TPR-(1-FPR) is nearest to zero in the  current example.

## Output:

```
        1-fpr       fpr        tf     thresholds       tpr
  171  0.637363  0.362637  0.000433    0.317628     0.637795
```

[image]

Hope this is helpful.

## Edit

To simplify and bring in re-usability, I have made a function to find the optimal probability cutoff point.

#### Python Code:

```
def Find_Optimal_Cutoff(target, predicted):
    """ Find the optimal probability cutoff point for a classification model related to event rate
    Parameters
    ----------
    target : Matrix with dependent or target data, where rows are observations

    predicted : Matrix with predicted data, where rows are observations

    Returns
    -------     
    list type, with optimal cutoff value
        
    """
    fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(target, predicted)
    i = np.arange(len(tpr)) 
    roc = pd.DataFrame({'tf' : pd.Series(tpr-(1-fpr), index=i), 'threshold' : pd.Series(threshold, index=i)})
    roc_t = roc.iloc[(roc.tf-0).abs().argsort()[:1]]

    return list(roc_t['threshold']) 


# Add prediction probability to dataframe
data['pred_proba'] = result.predict(data[train_cols])

# Find optimal probability threshold
threshold = Find_Optimal_Cutoff(data['admit'], data['pred_proba'])
print threshold
# [0.31762762459360921]

# Find prediction to the dataframe applying threshold
data['pred'] = data['pred_proba'].map(lambda x: 1 if x > threshold else 0)

# Print confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(data['admit'], data['pred'])
# array([[175,  98],
#        [ 46,  81]])
```

Comment: Is there a simple method to apply this threshold value to the predictions? Or do you just use an `apply` type function on the `data['preds']`?

Comment: @ skmathur, I have made it as a function for re-usability & simplification. Hope this helps.

Comment: There's a problem with your formula for Youden's Index in the `Find_Optimal_Cutoff` function. `roc_curve` returns `fpr` which is the false positive rate (1-specificity).  You're subtracting `(1-fpr)`. You need to change the `tpr-(1-fpr)` to `tpr-fpr`.

Comment: Epi package in R chooses the cutoff that maximizes (specificity + sensitivity). Hence, it should be tpr + (1-fpr) and not tpr - (1-fpr) as given in the code

Comment: @JohnBonfardeci Is it just me? I have the feeling OPs solution is producing the wrong result .. Shouldn't it be `pd.Series(tpr-fpr, index=thresholds, name='tf').idxmax()` ?

Comment: If applying this method to MNLogit with binary outcome, change the line `fpr, tpr, thresholds =roc_curve(data['admit'], data['pred'])` to `fpr, tpr, thresholds =roc_curve(data['admit'], data['pred'][:, 1])`.

Comment: I don't understand why this reply has the most upvotes. @JohnBonfardeci and @ StefanFalk are right, the formula is incorrect. Besides that, the axis discribtions of the plot are also wrong, there should be a double y-axis or a legend for the tpr and fpr and the x-axis is actually the thresholds.

Answer (score 72):

Given tpr, fpr, thresholds from your question, the answer for the optimal threshold is just:

```
optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr)
optimal_threshold = thresholds[optimal_idx]
```

Comment: what if I get negative optimal_threshold ...., My output prediction is in the range [0,1]...

Comment: Using

    optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr)
    optimal_threshold = thresholds[optimal_idx]

as suggested does not work for me. The thresholds array contains negative values, but I expected values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @rafaelcaballero "does not work"? Everything you described sounds like it's working correctly. It should not be between 0 and 1. It's just a score.

Comment: Then I missunderstood the question. I thought that the threshold moved between 0 and 1, and that the goal was to find the value in this range that maximized tpr-fpr

Comment: @cgnorthcutt Your code is correct. But TPR = TP/(real positive), FPR = FP/(real negative). TPR + FPR != 1.

Comment: @Qinsi - Yup. That's why I say "it should not be between 0 and 1. It's just a score," above. Its a good point, though. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 19):

Vanilla Python Implementation of Youden's J-Score

```
def cutoff_youdens_j(fpr,tpr,thresholds):
    j_scores = tpr-fpr
    j_ordered = sorted(zip(j_scores,thresholds))
    return j_ordered[-1][1]
```

Answer (score 8):

Another possible solution.

I'll create some random data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as sps
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, RocCurveDisplay, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# define data distributions
N0 = 300
N1 = 250

dist0 = sps.gamma(a=8, scale=1/10)
x0 = np.linspace(dist0.ppf(0), dist0.ppf(1-1e-5), 100)
y0 = dist0.pdf(x0)

dist1 = sps.gamma(a=15, scale=1/10)
x1 = np.linspace(dist1.ppf(0), dist1.ppf(1-1e-5), 100)
y1 = dist1.pdf(x1)

with plt.style.context("bmh"):
    plt.plot(x0, y0, label="NEG")
    plt.plot(x1, y1, label="POS")
    plt.legend()
    plt.title("Gamma distributions")
```

[image]

```
# create a random dataset
rvs0 = dist0.rvs(N0, random_state=0)
rvs1 = dist1.rvs(N1, random_state=1)

with plt.style.context("bmh"):
    plt.hist(rvs0, alpha=.5, label="NEG")
    plt.hist(rvs1, alpha=.5, label="POS")
    plt.legend()
    plt.title("Random dataset")
```

[image]

Initialize a dataframe with observations (x feature and y target)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "y": np.concatenate(( np.repeat(0, N0) , np.repeat(1, N1) )),
    "x": np.concatenate(( rvs0             , rvs1             )),
})
```

and display it with a box plot

```
# plot the data
with plt.style.context("bmh"):
    g = sns.catplot(
        kind="box",
        data=df,
        x="y", y="x"
    )
    ax = g.axes.flat[0]
    sns.stripplot(
        data=df,
        x="y", y="x",
        ax=ax, color='k',
        alpha=.25
    )
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, we can split the dataframe into train-test, perform Logistic regression, compute ROC curve, AUC, Youden's index, find the cut-off and plot everything. All using `pandas`

```
# split dataset into train-test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df[["x"]], df.y.values, test_size=0.5, random_state=1)
# init and fit Logistic Regression on train set
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# predict probabilities on x test set
y_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
# compute FPR and TPR from y test set and predicted probabilities
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(
    y_test, y_proba[:,1], drop_intermediate=False)
# compute ROC AUC
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
# init a dataframe for results
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": X_test.x.values.flatten(),
    "y": y_test,
    "proba": y_proba[:,1]
})
# sort it by predicted probabilities
# because thresholds[1:] = y_proba[::-1]
df_test.sort_values(by="proba", inplace=True)
# add reversed TPR and FPR
df_test["tpr"] = tpr[1:][::-1]
df_test["fpr"] = fpr[1:][::-1]
# optional: add thresholds to check
#df_test["thresholds"] = thresholds[1:][::-1]
# add Youden's j index
df_test["youden_j"] = df_test.tpr - df_test.fpr
# define the cut_off and diplay it
cut_off = df_test.sort_values(
    by="youden_j", ascending=False, ignore_index=True).iloc[0]
print("CUT-OFF:")
print(cut_off)

# plot everything
with plt.style.context("bmh"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
    
    RocCurveDisplay(
        fpr=df_test.fpr, tpr=df_test.tpr,
        roc_auc=roc_auc).plot(ax=ax[0])
    ax[0].set_title("ROC curve")
    ax[0].axline(xy1=(0,0), slope=1, color="r", ls=":")
    ax[0].plot(cut_off.fpr, cut_off.tpr, 'ko', ms=10)
    
    df_test.plot(
        x="youden_j", y="proba", ax=ax[1], 
        ylabel="Predicted Probabilities", xlabel="Youden j",
        title="Youden's index", legend=False
    )
    ax[1].axvline(cut_off.youden_j, color="k", ls="--")
    ax[1].axhline(cut_off.proba, color="k", ls="--")
    
    df_test.plot(
        x="x", y="proba", ax=ax[2], 
        ylabel="Predicted Probabilities", xlabel="X Feature",
        title="Cut-Off", legend=False
    )
    ax[2].axvline(cut_off.x, color="k", ls="--")
    ax[2].axhline(cut_off.proba, color="k", ls="--")

    plt.show()
```

and we get

```
CUT-OFF:
x           1.065712
y           1.000000
proba       0.378543
tpr         0.852713
fpr         0.143836
youden_j    0.708878
```

[image]

We can finally check

```
# check results
TP = df_test[(df_test.x>=cut_off.x)&(df_test.y==1)].index.size
FP = df_test[(df_test.x>=cut_off.x)&(df_test.y==0)].index.size
TN = df_test[(df_test.x< cut_off.x)&(df_test.y==0)].index.size
FN = df_test[(df_test.x< cut_off.x)&(df_test.y==1)].index.size

print("True Positive Rate: ", TP / (TP + FN))
print("False Positive Rate:", 1 - TN / (TN + FP))
```

```
True Positive Rate:  0.8527131782945736
False Positive Rate: 0.14383561643835618
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, it does however not account for non unique probabilites. roc_curve returns a value for each unique probability, yet the line `df_test["tpr"] = tpr[1:][::-1]` error, for any df that was created with unique y_proba

Comment: I suggest, dropping all duplicates regarding to the column `"proba" ` in `df_test ` right after its creation.

Answer (score 5):

Although I am late to the party, but you can also use Geometric Mean to determine the optimal threshold as stated here: [threshold tuning for imbalance classification](https://machinelearningmastery.com/threshold-moving-for-imbalanced-classification/)

It can be computed as:

```
# calculate the g-mean for each threshold
gmeans = sqrt(tpr * (1-fpr))
# locate the index of the largest g-mean
ix = argmax(gmeans)
print('Best Threshold=%f, G-Mean=%.3f' % (thresholds[ix], gmeans[ix]))
```

Comment: Use of `sqrt` seems unnecessary here. Argmax works same without it.

Comment: What optimal does it give us? Wouldn't it contradict with Youden's index for this example: `tpr=0.5 & fpr=0.5` and `tpr=0.55 & fpr=0.45`?