# How to calculate ROC curve in python using my own classified dataset?

Tags: python, roc, auc

I have a dataset that contains two columns:

i) **Column A:** Absolute binary values (0 and 1) represent the ground truth.
ii) **Column B:** Values ranging from 0 to 1 (e.g., 0.2, 0.33, 0.82) represent my new new test results.

How can I calculate the sensitivity & specificity (maximized using Youden index), ROC curve and AUC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot ROC curve in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009284/how-to-plot-roc-curve-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roc curve and cut off point. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719067/roc-curve-and-cut-off-point-python)

Answer (score 0):

[scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html#) includes methods to calculate these for you. You can find them [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).